# how to div width automatically adjust inside images / content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width

**Demo Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/2gqy9s9k/1/

container have 4 blocks..Each `div` contain  `width:25%`.. so fulfill the  container...

If i remove any one `div` container have empty space.. but I want to again fulfill the container.. 
Its is possible?

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #333
}
.badge-block{
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
 }
.badge-block img{ 
    width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display: table;` & `display: table-cell` for this. Im pretty sure this is what you mean.

Table cells take up the left over space. So just use it like this, take one of the images out and you will see how it works.

[**Demo Here Too**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gqy9s9k/2/)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: table;
}
.badge-block {
  display: table-cell;
}
.badge-block img {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="badge-block">
    <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon">
      <img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive">
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="badge-block">
    <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon">
      <img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive">
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="badge-block">
    <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon">
      <img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive">
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="badge-block">
    <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon">
      <img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that made me happy :)

Comment: @user10 Excellent, any questions about this please feel free to come back and ask.

Answer (score 4):

`display: table-cell` is your friend here.

```css
.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #333;
    display: table;
}
.badge-block{
    display: table-cell;
}
.badge-block img{ 
    width:80%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you only need to support modern browsers you can use flexbox...

```css
.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #333;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.badge-block img{ 
    width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
 <div class="badge-block">
  <a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoting for the Flexbox way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display: table` on you container with `table-layout: fixed` to fix same width in your columns.
In your div (cells) you can apply `display: table-cell` and remove float.

Like so:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; // Fix all columns to same width
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #333
}
.badge-block {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2gqy9s9k/4/

Answer (score 0):

The classic way is with `display: table-cell`, but Flexbox is definitely the future.

With [Flexbox](http://html5please.com/#flexbox) you can achieve this easily, and all the major browsers are nowadays supporting it in its third version, the "standard" one.

Run the code snippet and scroll down.

```css
.container{      
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.badge-block{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-responsive{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div> <div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div> <div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div> <div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div> <div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div></div><div class="container"><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div></div><div class="container"><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div></div><div class="container"><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div></div><div class="container"><div class="badge-block"><a href="javascript::" data-toggle="tooltip" title="General Pack Rs.50" class="badge-icon"><img src="http://www.globalniche.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/badge1.png" class="img-responsive"> </a></div></div>
```

Don't miss the [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and take a look at [Flexy Boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/), an amazing tool to create already prefixed Flex code visually.