# calculate space for inline-block elements with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a website header/navigation bar. On the left side I have a logo area, on the right side are a few buttons/links, and in the middle, I have a filler empty space so the logo gets pushed to the left, and the links get pushed to the right.

Basically I have everything as `inline-block` elements, inside a parent who has `text-align: center`. This way they are centered on the screen, but still expand to the left and right. Also, everything is inside of a `div` that is `90%` of the full width of the screen, so there is some extra space on the sides.

[Here's a fiddle to demo what I have](https://jsfiddle.net/u93wwLvv/1/)

The problem is, when the window is really big, the logo isn't far enough to the left and the links aren't far enough to the right (I want them to basically be right on the far edges of the 90% width centered parent). However, when the window gets small, its perfect (especially before my media query comes into effect).

I've used 50% width as the filler space in the middle, but I need a larger space when the window gets bigger (maybe like `80%` filler space), is there a way to make the `width %` for the empty space get bigger as the window resizes with just css (and without like 20 media queries for every 100 pixels size difference)?

If the logo and links had set `width` properties, I can use `calc()` but they don't, and I'd like to avoid settings static widths

> Also, I don't want to use floats!!!

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats?

Comment: @hungerstar because floats sometimes screw up styles, like setting the bar height relative to the elements inside. If you see my example, I just use some padding on all the text, and that constitutes the height of the overall bar. If I use floats, I have to do it another way, which requires more html/css, and containers, and set heights, and widths, margins, etc.. and it becomes ugly

Comment: Not sure if I agree with all that, would something like this be out of the question? https://jsfiddle.net/u93wwLvv/9/

Comment: @hungerstar no I guess that's not out of question, but I don't know what that before/after stuff does :) but seems to be doing the right thing

Comment: There's a number of confusing aspects to floats, well at first there is. One of them is a float takes and element out of the normal document flow, i.e they don't take up space within a containing element. So the containing element collapses. If all child elements were floated, visually the containing element will behave as if it didn't contain any elements. The `:before` and `:after` are pseudo elements that are used as part of a clearfix. A clearfix has been used for quite some time to make the containing element behave as if the floated child elements took up space,  Google it.

Comment: @hungerstar ah I see, ok so that makes sense now. Thank you for clarifying. I guess with clear fixes it makes more sense to use the floats. Thanks for the long response, very helpful info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. `float`, `display: table` / `table-cell`, and certainly `flex`.

Flex is new, but is most likely the future, and its current version is a lot more standard than the previous ones.

Check out the running demo created with the [FlexyBoxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=center&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) tool:

#### [Running demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/u93wwLvv/4/)

Created with basically only the flex settings, the `white-space: nowrap` on the `<ul>` and the `flex-container{ display: inline-block; }` in the media query for low resolution.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920905/1654265) potentially interesting answer.

Comment: dam thats a lot of css for the flex rules, but I like the result

Comment: It's autogenerated, and most of the properties are in their default value, but specified the same. It is also prefixed... you can keep I guess 4 rows of the total rules and it works the same ;) P.S: the first time I've seen the code generated by flexyboxes it I've thought the same, it's damn scary :D

Comment: that's what I like to hear, AUTOGENERATED!

Comment: Take a look at the FlexyBoxes link in my answer ;) I've not written almost anything

Answer (score 2):

I sense you are looking for display:table / table-cell rather than `inline-block`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u93wwLvv/7/)

```css
#bar {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #eee;
}
.space {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 3px;
}
.text-padding {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.centered {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: tomato;
  display: table;
}
.centered div {
  display: table-cell;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width: 330px) {
  .logo-text {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation {
    display: block;
  }
  .li {
    display: block;
  }
  .space {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='bar'>
  <div class='centered text-align-center'>
    <div class='text-padding logo-text'>
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class='space'></div>
    <div class='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li class='li text-padding'>
          one
        </li>
        <li class='li text-padding'>
          two
        </li>
        <li class='li text-padding'>
          three
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*** Edited to provide a solution without floats ***

You could just add another media query to adjust the spacer size when the screen width allows:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .space {
    width: 70%;
  }  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u93wwLvv/8/

Add as many media queries as you like.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use floats...it's in the question.

Comment: Sorry yeah... noticing that now.  Answer changed accordingly.

Comment: thats better, I think media queries are ok, as long as not too many are required